# PDO Multiple SQLite Inserts with Subquery

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sqlite, prepared-statement

**EDIT: I've posted [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653033/pdo-sqlite-foreach-insert-bindparam-bindvalue-not-inserting-rows) (rather than an edit) as the content and code I've tried is very lengthy and would mean completely replacing this question.**

I'm working on `INSERT`ing multiple rows into an SQLite table using PDO, but I'm having trouble executing my query using bound parameters. I've got three tables with the schema:

columns schoolB_equivalencies:

- equivalency_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
- schoolA_id INTEGER NOT NULL
- schoolB_id INTEGER NOT NULL
- is_archived INTEGER NOT NULL
- FOREIGN KEY (schoolA_id) REFERENCES schoolA_courses (id)
- FOREIGN KEY (schoolB_id) REFERENCES schoolB_courses (id)

columns for schoolA_courses:

- schoolA_courses id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
- course_prefix TEXT
- course_number INTEGER
- ...other fields

columns for schoolB_courses:

- schoolB_courses id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
- course_prefix TEXT
- course_number INTEGER
- ...other fields

I'm attempting to make multiple inserts at once with `prepare()`, an array of values, and a subquery. Running the `INSERT` statement once works (one row is inserted):

```
$dir = 'sqlite:/path/to/courses.sqlite3';
$dbh  = new PDO($dir) or die("error");

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO schoolB_equivalencies (schoolA_id, schoolB_id, is_archived) VALUES ( (SELECT id from schoolA_courses WHERE course_number="103" AND course_prefix="RPED"), (SELECT id from schoolB_courses WHERE course_number="251" AND course_prefix="ARCH"),0)');

$stmt->execute();
```

However, when I incorporate the same statement using bound parameters and an array of values, no rows are inserted:

```
$dir = 'sqlite:/path/to/courses.sqlite3';
$dbh  = new PDO($dir) or die("error");

$selections = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => "RPED", // THE schoolA COURSE PREFIX
        1 => "103", //THE schoolA COURSE NUMBER
        2 => "ARCH", //THE schoolB COURSE PREFIX
        3 => "251" //THE schoolB COURSE NUMBER
    ),
    1 => array(
        0 => "RPED", // THE schoolA COURSE PREFIX
        1 => "126", //THE schoolA COURSE NUMBER
        2 => "ARCH", //THE schoolB COURSE PREFIX
        3 => "261" //THE schoolB COURSE NUMBER
    )
);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO schoolB_equivalencies (schoolA_id, schoolB_id, is_archived) VALUES ( (SELECT id from schoolA_courses WHERE course_number=:schoolA_code AND course_prefix=:schoolA_prefix), (SELECT id from schoolB_courses WHERE course_number=:schoolB_code AND course_prefix=:schoolB_prefix),0)');

foreach ( $selections as $selection ):

    $stmt->bindParam(':schoolA_number', $selection[1]);
    $stmt->bindParam(':schoolA_prefix', $selection[0]);
    $stmt->bindParam(':schoolB_number', $selection[3]);
    $stmt->bindParam(':schoolB_prefix', $selection[2]);
    $stmt->execute();

    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());

endforeach;
```

The output of `error_info()` shows code 0000 on both inserts, which appears to be a "success" indicator, but no rows are being inserted. Based on the fact that the single `INSERT` works and that `error_info()` is reporting success, I'm guessing there's something wrong with how I'm binding parameters.

Comment: you are executing twice the query inside your loop

Comment: I've moved `$stmt->execute();` outside the loop, but the statement still doesn't `INSERT` any rows.

Comment: move the query statement inside the foreach loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO SQLite foreach INSERT: bindParam(), bindValue() not inserting rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653033/pdo-sqlite-foreach-insert-bindparam-bindvalue-not-inserting-rows)

Answer (score 0):

To begin with...Shouldn't it be

```
$stmt->bindParam(':schoolA_number', $selection[0][1]);
$stmt->bindParam(':schoolA_prefix', $selection[0][0]);
$stmt->bindParam(':schoolB_number', $selection[0][3]);
$stmt->bindParam(':schoolB_prefix', $selection[0][2]);
```

OR

```
$stmt->bindParam(':schoolA_number', $selection[1][1]);
$stmt->bindParam(':schoolA_prefix', $selection[1][0]);
$stmt->bindParam(':schoolB_number', $selection[1][3]);
$stmt->bindParam(':schoolB_prefix', $selection[1][2]);
```

OR

```
foreach ( $selections as $selection ) {
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO schoolB_equivalencies (schoolA_id, schoolB_id, is_archived) VALUES ( (SELECT id from schoolA_courses WHERE course_number=:schoolA_code AND course_prefix=:schoolA_prefix), (SELECT id from schoolB_courses WHERE course_number=:schoolB_code AND course_prefix=:schoolB_prefix),0)');
   $stmt->bindParam(':schoolA_number', $selection[1]);
   $stmt->bindParam(':schoolA_prefix', $selection[0]);
   $stmt->bindParam(':schoolB_number', $selection[3]);
   $stmt->bindParam(':schoolB_prefix', $selection[2]);
   $stmt->execute();
   print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
}
```

AND NOT

```
foreach ( $selections as $selection ) {

   $stmt->bindParam(':schoolA_number', $selection[1]);
   $stmt->bindParam(':schoolA_prefix', $selection[0]);
   $stmt->bindParam(':schoolB_number', $selection[3]);
   $stmt->bindParam(':schoolB_prefix', $selection[2]);
   $stmt->execute();

   ...

}
```